# Issue while Exceuting a perl Script : ./Test.pl: Command not found

Tags: perl

Dos2Unix worked..Thanks to slayedbylucifer!!

Now I am getting the following error:

```
Global symbol "$path" requires explicit package name at ./Test.pl line 4.
Global symbol "$path" requires explicit package name at ./Test.pl line 5.
Execution of ./Test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I am executing my program as 
./Test.pl "/scratch/samaggar/AutoSuite"

and here is the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 $path = $ARGV[0];
 process_files($path);

 sub process_files {
     my $path = shift;
     opendir (DIR, $path)
     or die "Unable to open $path: $!";

     my @files = grep { !/^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir (DIR);
     closedir (DIR);
     @files = map { $path . '/' . $_ } @files;

     for (@files) {
         if (-d $_) {
             process_files ($_);
         } else {
             print @files;
         }
     }
}
```

Please suggest. What is the issue..

Comment: have you given the file execute permission? `chmod +x Test.pl` and is the file `test.pl` or `Test.pl` as linux is case sensitive

Comment: oh and don't forget to `use strict;use warnings;` at the top of your file. Welcome to the wonderful world of perl

Comment: I have checked the file permissions its:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 samaggar dba 1529 Feb 24 21:33 Test.pl

Comment: Added use strict;use warnings;  but same error..
Also a simple script like the one below is working fine:
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Hello World.\n";

Please help!!

Comment: @user2150950 You should not use complete permissions on a file (777). It means anyone can edit the file and execute it, which is a security risk.

Comment: @user2150950 Also, when it comes to asking questions, you should not change the question completely and ask another question when you get an answer. Accept the answer so that the person who wrote it gets credit for the answer, then ask a *new* question with the new information.

Comment: @user2150950 Lastly, you are trying to reinvent the wheel. This functionality is already implemented in a core Perl module: [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind). You are making the mistake of printing all the `@files` once for each file in the array.

Answer (score 0):

use `dos2unix` on your script as below:

```
$ dos2unix <script_name>
```

I had faced similar issues in the past due to some invisible stuff in my script.

If you are using ubuntu (or something similar), then use `fromdos` instead of `dos2unix`

**UPDATE:**

Here is a quick simulation of your script:

```
$ cat test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $path=$ARGV[0];
print $path."\n";


$ ./test.pl "/scratch/samaggar/AutoSuite"
/scratch/samaggar/AutoSuite
```

Note that I have used `my` while defining the `$path` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It worked..Now I am getting compilation errors like:
Global symbol "$path" requires explicit package name at ./Test.pl line 2.
Global symbol "$path" requires explicit package name at ./Test.pl line 3.
Execution of ./Test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Can you help me on this?I want my script to accept some unix path as input and it can work on that path to list all the files and directories inside it.

Comment: put `use strict; use warnings` in your script, then run it, and then post the errors in your question with proper formatting.

Comment: @user2150950, you should [Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) and [Upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/244809) an answer if it was helpful to you. That's the ONLY way to say **Thanks** on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

when strict is used (use strict;),the declaration should me mentioned global or local

my $path; (helps you to declare $path as local variable)

or

our $path;(declares $path as global so it can be exported)